# PIN in Arduino = 0 does not trigger the motors

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, atmega

I am trying to use if statement to control the motors using C on the Arduino Uno board. However, when I set so that when the PIN, which is the sensor equals 0, the motors will run, it does not work at all. I also tried setting the PIN to not equal 0 and 1, both working fine. Can you guys give it a check? Thank you very much.

```
int MotorL=11;
int DirectionR=12;
int MotorR=10;
int DirectionL=13;
int SensorM=0;

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


void setup() {
  pinMode(DirectionL,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DirectionR,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SensorM,INPUT);
  digitalWrite(DirectionL,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DirectionR,HIGH);
  analogWrite(MotorL,0);
  analogWrite(MotorR,0);
}

void loop() {
  if(PIND &_BV(PD6)==0){ //General movement: forward
    analogWrite(MotorL,84);
    analogWrite(MotorR,97);
  }else{
    analogWrite(MotorL,0);
    analogWrite(MotorR,0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`. You need to put the first two terms in parenthesis.

What you mean is:

```
if((PIND &_BV(PD6))==0)
```

But what the compiler sees is:

```
if(PIND & (_BV(PD6)==0))
```